# In Erlang, what's the difference between gen_server:start() and gen_server:start_link()?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server

Can someone explain what's the difference between `gen_server:start()` and `gen_server:start_link()`?

I've been told that it's something about multi threading stuff.

**EDIT:**
If my gen_server is called from multiple threads, will it execute them all at once ? Or will it create concurrency between these threads?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both functions start new `gen_server` instances as children of the calling process, but they differ in that the [`gen_server:start_link/3,4`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#start_link-3) atomically starts a `gen_server` child and *links it to its parent process*. Linking means that if the child dies, the parent will by default also die. [Supervisors](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html) are parent processes that use links to take specific actions when their child processes exit abnormally, typically restarting them.

Other than the linking involved in the `gen_server:start_link` case, there are no multi-process aspects involved in these calls. Regardless of whether you use `gen_server:start` or `gen_server:start_link` to start a new `gen_server`, the new process has a single message queue, and it receives and processes those messages one at a time. There is nothing about `gen_server:start_link` that causes the new `gen_server` process to behave or perform differently than it would if started with `gen_server:start`.

Comment: I've already answered what's in your edit. If multiple processes call your `gen_server` concurrently, their messages are queued in the `gen_server` message queue, and the `gen_server` processes those messages one at a time.

Answer (score 5):

When you use `gen_server:start_link` new process becomes "child" of calling process - it's part of **supervision tree**. It allows calling process to be notified if gen_server process dies.

Using `gen_server:start` will spawn process outside of supervision tree.

Nice description of supervision in Erlang is here: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/supervisors

Comment: If my genserver  is called from multiple threads, will it execute them all at once ? or will it create concurrency between theese threads?

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you answer me on that as well?

Comment: Erlang does not use term "thread". It's called "process". If multiple process call the same gen_server, they requests will be put into queue and handled one after another. On http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content there is very nice part about OTP